# Kendo mvc grid detail templates with columns bounded to editor templates within tabstrip

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a mvc4 razor view consists of a Kendo mvc grid with detail templates which are also Kendo mvc grids within each tab of a Kendo Tabstrip.

Each detail grids are linked to the master grid via the unique ID of the master grid.
All the grids can render without problem when the columns are text.

However, once I starting to customize some columns, i.e. replacing text column by EditorTemplate, then the grids won't render anymore. I used ForeignKeyColumn in some of the columns and they worked but due to the record size of certain columns, I have to use EditorTemplate to customize the source and limit the number of records pass to the client each time.

Here's my code for the view.

```html
    ﻿﻿@(Html.Kendo().Grid<EMD.DAL.Domain.Attribute.AssetSubType>()
      .Name("subTypeGrid")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
    columns.Bound(c => c.AssetSubTypeID).Hidden();
          columns.ForeignKey(c => c.AssetTypeID, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["assetTypes"], "AssetTypeID", "Type").Width(200);
          columns.Bound(c => c.SubType).Width(300);
          columns.Bound(c => c.Description).Width(300);
          columns.Bound(c => c.ProductTypeID).Width(100);
          columns.Bound(c => c.PhysicalItem).Width(100);
          columns.Bound(c => c.LastModified).Hidden();
          columns.Bound(c => c.LastModifiedBy).Hidden();
          columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(180);
      })
   .
   .
      .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
   .ClientDetailTemplateId("SubTypeChildrenTemplate")
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Ajax()
          .Model(model =>
          {
              model.Id(p => p.AssetSubTypeID);
         })
 )  

 <script id="SubTypeChildrenTemplate" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
    @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
            .Name("tabStrip_#=AssetSubTypeID#")
            .SelectedIndex(0)
            .Items(tabStrip =>
            {
                tabStrip.Add().Text("Specs").Content(@<text>
                    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<EMD.DAL.Domain.Attribute.SubTypeSpec>()
                            .Name("specGrid_#=AssetSubTypeID#")
                            .Columns(columns =>
                            {
                                columns.ForeignKey(o => o.SubTypeSpecCategoryID, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["subTypeSpecsCat"], "SubTypeSpecCategoryID", "SpecCategory").Title("SpecCategory").Width(100);
                                columns.Bound(o => o.Spec).Width(100);
                                columns.Bound(o => o.SpecValue).Title("SpecValue").Width(100);
                                columns.ForeignKey(o => o.UnitID, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["specUnits"], "UnitID", "SpecUnit").Width(50).Title("Unit");
                                columns.Bound(o => o.Comment).Width(100);
                                columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(180);
                            })
                            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                .Ajax()
                                .Model(model =>
                                {
                                    model.Id(p => p.SubTypeSpecID);
                                })
                                .Read(read => read.Action("SubTypeSpecs_Read", "AssetAttribute", new { assetSubTypeID = "#=AssetSubTypeID#" }))
                                .Update(update => update.Action("SubTypeSpecs_Update", "AssetAttribute"))
                                .Create(update => update.Action("SubTypeSpecs_Create", "AssetAttribute").Data("onAddSubItem"))
                                .Destroy(update => update.Action("SubTypeSpecs_Destroy", "AssetAttribute"))
                             )
        .
        .
                             .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
                             .ToClientTemplate()
                    )
                </text>);
                tabStrip.Add().Text("Attributes").Content(@<text>
            ﻿﻿         @(Html.Kendo().Grid<EMD.DAL.Domain.Attribute.SubTypeAttribute>()
                        .Name("attributeGrid_#=AssetSubTypeID#")
                        .Columns(columns =>
                        {
                            columns.ForeignKey(c => c.AttributeValueID, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["attributes"], "AttributeValueID", "Attribute").Title("Attribute").Width(200);
                            columns.Bound(c => c.DefaultValue);
                            columns.Bound(c => c.Description);
                            columns.Bound(c => c.LastModified).Hidden();
                            columns.Bound(c => c.LastModifiedBy).Hidden();
                            columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(180);
                        })
                        .
                        .
                        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
                        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                            .Ajax()
                            .PageSize(5)
                            .Model(model =>
                            {
                                model.Id(p => p.SubTypeAttributeID);
                                model.Field(p => p.SubTypeAttributeID).Editable(false);
                                model.Field(p => p.LastModified).Editable(false);
                                model.Field(p => p.LastModifiedBy).Editable(false);
                            })
                            .Read(read => read.Action("SubTypeAttributes_Read", "AssetAttribute", new { assetSubTypeID = "#=AssetSubTypeID#" }))
                            .Create(create => create.Action("SubTypeAttributes_Create", "AssetAttribute").Data("onAddSubItem"))
                            .Update(update => update.Action("SubTypeAttributes_Update", "AssetAttribute"))
                            .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("SubTypeAttributes_Destroy", "AssetAttribute"))
                        )
                        .ToClientTemplate()
     )
                </text>);
                tabStrip.Add().Text("Parts").Content(@<text>
            ﻿﻿  @(Html.Kendo().Grid<EMD.DAL.Domain.Attribute.SubTypePartList>()
                        .Name("partGrid_#=AssetSubTypeID#")
                        .Columns(columns =>
                        {
                            columns.Bound(c => c.ParentID).Hidden();
                            columns.Bound(c => c.AssetSubType).Title("SubType").ClientTemplate("\\#=AssetSubType.SubType\\#").EditorTemplateName("SubTypeEditor");
                            columns.Bound(c => c.SPartID);
                            columns.Bound(c => c.Qty);
                            columns.Bound(c => c.Description);
                            columns.Bound(c => c.InsideParent);
                            columns.Bound(c => c.LastModified).Hidden();
                            columns.Bound(c => c.LastModifiedBy).Hidden();
                            columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(180);
                        })
      .
                        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
                        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                            .Ajax()
                            .Model(model =>
                            {
                                model.Id(p => p.ID);
        model.Field(p => p.AssetSubType);
                            })
                            .Read(read => read.Action("SubTypePartLists_Read", "AssetAttribute", new { assetSubTypeID = "#=AssetSubTypeID#" }))
                            .Create(create => create.Action("SubTypePartLists_Create", "AssetAttribute").Data("onAddSubItem"))
                            .Update(update => update.Action("SubTypePartLists_Update", "AssetAttribute"))
                            .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("SubTypePartLists_Destroy", "AssetAttribute"))
                        )
                        .ToClientTemplate()
     )
                </text>);
                tabStrip.Add().Text("Asset Items").Content(@<text>
            ﻿﻿  @(Html.Kendo().Grid<EMD.Manager.ViewModels.AssetItemVM>()
                        .Name("assetItemsGrid_#=AssetSubTypeID#")
                        .Columns(columns =>
                        {
                            columns.Bound(c => c.Asset);
                            columns.Bound(c => c.Description);
                            columns.Bound(c => c.Location).Title("Location").ClientTemplate("\\#=Location.Asset\\#").EditorTemplateName("LocationEditor");
                            columns.Bound(c => c.Owner);
                            columns.Bound(c => c.LastModified).Hidden();
                            columns.Bound(c => c.LastModifiedBy).Hidden();
                            columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(180);
                        })
                        .ToolBar(toolbar =>
                        {
                            toolbar.Create().HtmlAttributes((new { onclick = "setMasterSubTypeID(this, #=AssetSubTypeID#)" }));
                        })
                       .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                            .Ajax()
                            .Model(model =>
                            {
                                model.Id(p => p.AssetItemID);
                                model.Field(p => p.Location);
                            })
                            .Read(read => read.Action("AssetItems_Read", "AssetAttribute", new { assetSubTypeID = "#=AssetSubTypeID#" }))
                            .Create(create => create.Action("AssetItems_Create", "AssetAttribute").Data("onAddSubItem"))
                            .Update(update => update.Action("AssetItems_Update", "AssetAttribute"))
                            .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("AssetItems_Destroy", "AssetAttribute"))
                        )
                        .ToClientTemplate()
     )
                </text>);
                tabStrip.Add().Text("SubType I/O").Content(@<text>
     @(Html.Kendo().Grid<EMD.DAL.Domain.Attribute.SubTypeIO>()
                            .Name("IOGrid_#=AssetSubTypeID#")
                            .Columns(columns =>
                            {
                                columns.ForeignKey(c => c.IOTypeID, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["ioTypes"], "IOTypeID", "IType").Title("I/OType").Width(50);
                                columns.ForeignKey(c => c.FieldDeviceTypeID, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["fieldDevices"], "FieldDeviceTypeID", "FieldDevice").Title("Field Device Type").Width(150);
                                columns.ForeignKey(c => c.EngUnitID, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["engUnits"], "EngUnitID", "EngineeringUnit").Title("Eng Unit").Width(100);
                                columns.Bound(c => c.IOTag);
                                columns.Bound(c => c.IODescription);
                                columns.Bound(c => c.IOModule);
                                columns.Bound(c => c.IOChannelNo);
                                columns.Bound(c => c.InputLow);
                                columns.Bound(c => c.InputHigh);
                                columns.Bound(c => c.MinEngValue);
                                columns.Bound(c => c.MaxEngValue);
                                columns.Bound(c => c.FATOnly);
                                columns.Bound(c => c.LastModified).Hidden();
                                columns.Bound(c => c.LastModifiedBy).Hidden();
                                columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(180);
                            })
                            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                .Ajax()
                                .Model(model =>
                                {
                                    model.Id(p => p.SubTypeIOID);
                                })
                                .Read(read => read.Action("SubTypeIOs_Read", "AssetAttribute", new { assetSubTypeID = "#=AssetSubTypeID#" }))
                                .Create(create => create.Action("SubTypeIOs_Create", "AssetAttribute").Data("onAddSubItem"))
                                .Update(update => update.Action("SubTypeIOs_Update", "AssetAttribute"))
                                .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("SubTypeIOs_Destroy", "AssetAttribute"))
                             )
                            .ToolBar(toolbar =>
                            {
                                toolbar.Create().HtmlAttributes((new { onclick = "setMasterSubTypeID(this, #=AssetSubTypeID#)" }));
                            })
                             .ToClientTemplate()
     )
                </text>);
            })
    )
</script>
```

Here's my two EditorTemplate.

```html
@model object
<script>
    function valueMapper(options) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("AssetItems_ValueMapper", "AssetAttribute")",
            data: convertValues(options.value),
            success: function (data) {
                options.success(data);
            }
        });
    }

    function convertValues(value) {
        var data = {};

        value = $.isArray(value) ? value : [value];

        for (var idx = 0; idx < value.length; idx++) {
            data["values[" + idx + "]"] = value[idx];
        }

        return data;
    }
</script>


@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
            .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "LocationDDL#=AssetSubTypeID#" })
            .Name("Location")
            .DataTextField("Asset")
            .DataValueField("AssetItemID")
        //.AutoBind(false)
            .Filter(FilterType.StartsWith)
            .MinLength(3)
            .DataSource(source =>
                    {
                        source.Custom()
                            .ServerFiltering(true)
                            .ServerPaging(true)
                            .ServerSorting(true)
                            .PageSize(5)
                            .Type("aspnetmvc-ajax")
                            .Transport(transport =>
                            {
                                transport.Read("AssetItemsDropDown_Read", "AssetAttribute");
                            })
                            .Schema(schema =>
                            {
                                schema.Data("Data").Total("Total");
                            });
                    })
        //.Events(events => events.Change("selected"))
        .Virtual(v => v.ItemHeight(26).ValueMapper("valueMapper"))
)
```

```html
@model object
<script>
    function valueMapper(options) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("SubTypes_ValueMapper", "AssetAttribute")",
            data: convertValues(options.value),
            success: function (data) {
                options.success(data);
            }
        });
    }

    function convertValues(value) {
        var data = {};

        value = $.isArray(value) ? value : [value];

        for (var idx = 0; idx < value.length; idx++) {
            data["values[" + idx + "]"] = value[idx];
        }

        return data;
    }

</script>
    @( Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
            .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "SubTypeDDL#=AssetSubTypeID#" })
            .Name("AssetSubType")
            .DataTextField("SubType")
            .DataValueField("AssetSubTypeID")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px" })
            .Filter(FilterType.StartsWith)
            .MinLength(3)
            .DataSource(source =>
                    {
                        source.Custom()
                            .ServerFiltering(true)
                            .ServerPaging(true)
                            .ServerSorting(true)
                            .PageSize(5)
                            .Type("aspnetmvc-ajax")
                            .Transport(transport =>
                            {
                                transport.Read("AssetSubTypesDropDown_Read", "AssetAttribute");
                            })
                            .Schema(schema =>
                            {
                                schema.Data("Data").Total("Total");
                            });
                    })
            .Virtual(v => v.ItemHeight(26).ValueMapper("valueMapper"))
            //.Events(events => events.Change("selected"))

    )
```

I found the lines causing the problem are both related to using EditorTemplate. The grids load again once I comment these two lines out.

columns.Bound(c => c.AssetSubType).Title("SubType").ClientTemplate("\#=AssetSubType.SubType\#").EditorTemplateName("SubTypeEditor");

columns.Bound(c => c.Location).Title("Location").ClientTemplate("\#=Location.Asset\#").EditorTemplateName("LocationEditor");

According to Kendo documentation, I have escaped the #hash by putting in two (2)\ backslashes (screen only shows one but I put two in the code) before each instance of # but the grids still don't render.

However, if I take out these detail grids and put them on a new view, they will work.

I tried to assign unique name to the DropDownList as well but it doesn't seem to help.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.